# How to use the same vocabulary to vectorize a new comment?

Tags: scikit-learn

Hello I am working with sklearn I have a list that looks as follows:

```
list = ["comment1","comment2",...,"commentN"]
```

then I builded a vectorizer to build a matrix,

```
tf_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(max_df=0.95, min_df=2,
                                max_features=n_features,stop_words=stpw)
```

I used fit_transform to vectorize this list

```
tf = tf_vectorizer.fit_transform(list)
```

I builded 8 clusters of data,

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=8, random_state=0).fit(tf)
```

and finally I used the method called predict to produce labels to every vector

```
y_pred = kmeans.predict(tf)
```

Now I have a new comment that I would like to associate with a cluster of my previos data,

```
comment = ["newComment"]
```

I tried, first vectorizing the comment to then use predict as follows:

```
newVec = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=tf.vocabulary_)

testComment = newVec.fit_transform(comment)
y_pred_Comment = kmeans.predict(comment)

print(y_pred_Comment)
```

The problem is that I am getting errors since this new vectorizer called newVec, is not taking all of my previos vocabulary,
I would like to appreciate help to vectorize my new comment but using the same model produced previously by tf_vectorizer.fit_transform(list),

Error associated:

```
<ipython-input-32-69c8879d551a> in <module>()
    129 
    130 
--> 131 newVec = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=tf.vocabulary_)
    132 
    133 comment = ["newComment"]

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py in __getattr__(self, attr)
    557             return self.getnnz()
    558         else:
--> 559             raise AttributeError(attr + " not found")
    560 
    561     def transpose(self, axes=None, copy=False):

AttributeError: vocabulary_ not found
```

Comment: it looks like you want to do `tf_vectorizer.vocabulary_`, since `tf` is just a sparse matrix.

Comment: the problem is that I want to apply kmeans to a new comment however I need to first vectorize this comment, I need fo find a way to use the same vocabulary in order to get a vector with the same dimension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've run into a slight misunderstanding of how the models are used in `scikit`. You want to train a model on your training set and then you apply the same model to your testing set. So in your example (but using the newsgroups data instead)

```
from sklearn import datasets, feature_extraction, neighbors, cluster

newsgroups_train = datasets.fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train').data[:200]
newsgroups_test = datasets.fetch_20newsgroups(subset='test').data[:100]

tf_vectorizer = feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer()
tf_train = tf_vectorizer.fit_transform(newsgroups_train)

kmeans = cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=8, random_state=0).fit(tf)
y_pred = kmeans.predict(tf_train)
```

Now we have a vectoriser and a clustering model we can apply it to new data.

```
tf_test = tf_vectorizer.transform(newsgroups_test)
y_pred_test = kmeans.predict(tf_test)
```

Comment: Well, @ncfirth my question is after it, if I have a new single new comment Can I use the previos model to vectorize  this comment and then use the same kmeans cluster or the previous model to classify this comment?

Comment: thanks for your support I was researching and I have the solution using Python Pickle Module for saving objects (serialization), with this I am able to save my models to vectorize new comments but using the same vocabulary and order....